# please can you explain me this code with examples

Tags: java

`Public static void main(String[] args)` please explain why here we make parameter array and why it is static what is args [].

Comment: static because the JVM shouldn't need to construct any objects before starting the application and `String[]` because you may invoke the application with string arguments from command line.

Comment: thank you for your answer here a little bit confusion i.e what is jvm and what is it work in java.

Comment: See [Lesson: A Closer Look at the "Hello World!" Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/) and [Command-Line Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

Answer (score 2):

static >It is used with main() and provide the advantage of static method that means there is no need to create an object to invoke the main method.

void > The main() is declared as void because it doesn't return any value.

String[] args >This parameter is used for command line arguments.so whatever argumnets passed on command line will be collected in args[] array.

for example

```
class CommandLineExample{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
System.out.println("Your first argument is: "+args[0]);
System.out.println("Your second argument is: "+args[1]);  
}  
}  

compile by > javac CommandLineExample.java  
run by > java CommandLineExample India USA
```

output:

```
Your first argument is: India
Your second argument is: USA
```

Comment: thank you for your answer here a little bit confusion i.e what is jvm and what is it work in java.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch your application from command prompt, then java interpreter looks for `public static void main(String[] args)` method in your application class and invokes it.

All command line parameters are passed to this method as array of Strings.

For instance if you call:

`java MyClass param1 param2 param3`

java interpreter invokes  `public static void main(String[] args)` of `MyClass` class and passes an array with elements `param1`, `param2`, `param3` as `args` parameter for this method.

If your class `MyClass` does not contain `public static void main(String[] args)` method, then you will get an error.

And let's explain `public static void main(String[] args)` modifiers.

- `public` - to be accessible outside of your class package.
- `static` - because it does not connected to `MyClass` instance, it can be invoked without building an object of `MyClass`.
- `void` - because this method returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`public` means that main() can be called from anywhere.
`static` means that main() doesn't belong to a specific object.
`void` means that main() returns no value.
`main` is the name of a function. main() is special because it is the start of the program.
`String[]` means an array of String.
`args` is the name of the String[] (within the body of main()). `args` is not special; you could name it anything else and the program would work the same.